# Can OpenCV do these processing?

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I am working on an OCR project. I need to do some pre-processing similar to the link below:
http://cn.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/automatically-detect-and-recognize-text-in-natural-images.html

The steps are:

- Region detection (MSER)
- Edge detection (Canny)
- Connected Component Analysis (for character candidates filtering)

I am not familiar with OpenCV. I am wondering if OpenCV can do all of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, OpenCV provides such functionalities.

Look also at [scene text detection and recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/text.html)